# WinJS AppBar button flash on Hide

Tags: windows-8, winjs, appbar

My application has a WinJS AppBar control at the bottom of the screen. I use `.showOnlyCommands(buttonsToShowArray)` to show and hide buttons on `ListView` `itemSelectionChanged` event.

The problem I have right now is that when every I call `.showOnlyCommands`, the buttons to be hidden (or you may say "replaced") are going to flash on the top of the screen.

I tried to use the Microsoft sample app, this doesn't happen. I tried to use `.showCommands` + `.hideCommands` method, it is the same behavior. Note that this didn't happen before the Release Preview version of Win8.

I have no idea what is going on. Any idea?

EDIT: 
I did further investigation, the problem happens on `hideCommands`. Say I have 3 buttons displayed on the appbar. I call `hideCommands` to hide all 3 buttons. The icon of the 3 buttons would disappear on the appbar, then pile up at the top-left corner of the screen and then disappear. (i.e. there would be a flash of 3 piled up buttons at the corner of the screen).

Answer (score 1):

You may be invoking showOnlyCommands when the AppBar is in the process of 'showing'. I've found that when calling these methods in the beforeshow or aftershow handler that this happens. This quote from [Animating your UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/hh465165.aspx) sheds light on why:

> Use fade in and fade out animations to show or hide transient UI or controls. One example is in an app bar in which new controls can appear due to user interaction.

The sample app shows/hides the buttons before the appbar is shown. You may be calling show on the app bar before calling showOnlyCommands.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think that's exactly what happened in my case. I am on vacation right now, so I couldn't test it on my own. But I will mark it as the correct answer as soon as i have a chance to implement it (in 2 wks)! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey @ChrisHerring , I am trying what you suggested. If we are not calling `showOnlyCommand` on `beforeShow`, how do you set what buttons to show when you do a right-click?

Comment: Your answer did help me to investigate forward, but it still didn't solve my problem. The problem still happens when I call `showOnlyCommands` when the appbar is up. When the buttons on appbar requires a change, I call `showOnlyCommands` instead of hiding and showing appbar, the flash still happens

Comment: If you call showOnlyCommands when the AppBar is up then you will see the flash, it is the expected behaviour as mentioned in the doco link I provided. You want to make your changes when the AppBar is hidden to avoid flashing. Try not to use the beforeshow event at all, change buttons when something happens in your app e.g. when a page is first loaded. Then when the AppBar is invoked the buttons are already correctly set.

Comment: So on Start Menu, updating the buttons wouldn't cause the flash though. I know Windows did a lot of things on Start Menu that are not supported in apps, is this one of them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If I change selected items with the AppBar visible then I see the buttons that change visibility flash also.

Comment: I guess we are probably not talking about the same thing then... I am not referring to the flashing "on" the app bar, but flashing outside of the app bar. My app bar is at the bottom of the screen, the flash happen on the top of the screen..

Answer (score 0):

A temporary hack for this problem is:

Set the button be invisible before calling `showOnlyCommands` or `HideCommands`.

Here is the code that I use for now:

```
/* 
 * @param {WinJS.UI.AppBar} appbar winControl
 * @param {Array} array of appbar buttons to be shown
 */
function showOnlyCommands(appbarControl, buttonsToShow) {
    var toShow = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < buttonsToShow.length; i++) {
        toShow[buttonsToShow[i].id] = true;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < visibleButtonsList.length; i++) {
        var id = visibleButtonsList[i].id;
        if (!toShow[id]) {
            // set the display property of the buttons to be hidden to "none"               
            var button = document.getElementById(id);
            if (button) {
                button.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
    // update the visible buttons list
    visibleButtonsList = buttonsToShow;
    // Note that we don't need to set the "display" property back for the buttons, 
    // because WinJS.UI.AppBar.showOnlyCommands would set it back internally
    appbarControl.showOnlyCommands(buttonsToShow);
}
```